# How it can stop after 15000px - Javascript scrollTo

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, scrolltop, scrollto

Here have an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/pusqN/light/
I wanna stop scrollTo animate after 15000px

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var myInterval = false;
myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    var iScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (iScroll + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    } else {
        iScroll = iScroll + 200;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: iScroll
        }, 1000);
    }
}, 2000);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Just add  the condition `iScroll + $(window).height() > 15000` in `if`:

```
...
if (iScroll + $(window).height() == $(document).height() ||
    iScroll + $(window).height() > 15000            // Stop after 15000px
   ) {
     clearInterval(myInterval);
}
...
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pusqN/39/)